# How can I change MVC2's validation messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm building an MVC2 project with C# and ASP.NET. In one of my forms I have a field that accepts a 'time' value. The field is using a JQuery UI Time picker but it still allows the user ot enter text him/herself (this is correct and needed this way). However when the user enters a value that is not a valid 'time' format an error message is displayed as follows:

```
The value 'garbage' is not valid for StartTime.
```

I need to change this validation message to something else. How do I do this? In the model the field is as follows:

```
    public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: You could look into writing a cutom validator.  There is a nice blog on it here that may help you - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Comment: you help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388238/validate-a-date-in-a-specific-format-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the solution I went for was turning the fields in the model to 'string' type and handling the validation of the data myself with TimeSpan.Parse and a 'Try Catch'. It's not the best solution but it beats involving custom validators and third party modules.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Below link to my post:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1718498.aspx/1?Validation+Message
,look at the marked answer,in two words You need:
http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wrong%20Format%20Errors
.In my project works well.