# How to validate date properly in mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to validate the date properly.If Iam entering the date as 21-2-198 instead of 21-2-1988
.The date is not validating properly in Mvc3.I used Regex for this but didn't be useful.Is any other method to validate the date including the year in MVC model.Following is the code i written in the model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Activation date is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Activation date")]
        [RegularExpression(@"/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/", ErrorMessage = "Enter proper date")]
        public DateTime? ActivationDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: I believe your requirement can be achieved as specified in the SO link below by creating new validation attribute for DateTime. [Date Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388238/validate-a-date-in-a-specific-format-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to get validation by using the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute instead of your regular expression.  Note that this Annotation is locale agnostic... i.e. `21-2-1988` and `2-21-1998` will both validate.

Comment: I mean its not validating the Year .

Answer (score 0):

> Iam entering the date as **21-2-198** instead of 21-2-1988 .The date is not validating properly in Mvc3.

It seems to me that you need a CustomValidator that prevents user to enter a date out of  specific range.

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Custom Validation using Data Annotations](http://weblogs.asp.net/brijmohan/archive/2012/01/24/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-validation-using-data-annotations.aspx) presents a Validator for this purpose.